# Woocommerce Cart Subtotal Display Wrong Amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use cart Widget as minicart details in top menu. In Mini cart details page display wrong cart subtotal (Product Amount without Discount). but checkout page display correct total amount how to fix it.

[image]

```
 if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0 ) { echo '<span class="circle" id="mini-cart-details">' .  WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . ' items - '.WC()->cart->get_cart_total().'</span>'; } else { echo '<span class="circle" id="mini-cart-details"> items - '.WC()->cart->get_cart_total().'</span>';  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with taxes. `$order->get_formatted_order_total()` returns incorrect and different value than `$order->get_total()`.